# Dropdown menu won't close when an item is clicked - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a responsive menu and am running into an issue with the last thing I am trying to do with it. When a menu item is clicked, it's navigating the page to the proper place, but it's not closing the menu.

Here's my code:

```
<a href="#" class="mobile">Menu</a>
 <ul class="menu mobile hide">
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#schedule">Schedule</a></li>
   <li><a href="#instructors">Instructors</a></li>
   <li><a href="#venue">Venue</a></li>
   <li><a href="#sponsors">Sponsors</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="menu-reg">Register Now</a></li>
  </ul>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('ul.mobile a').bind('vclick', function(){
    $('ul.menu.mobile').hide();
});
```

Comment: Should your selector be `$('ul.mobile').hide();`?

Comment: vclick is plugin attribute or what

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul.mobile a').bind('vclick click', function(){
    $('ul.menu').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$('ul.mobile a').bind('vclick', function(){
    $('ul.menu').hide();
});
```

Comment: vclick is plugin you are using?